# load images from library to UICollection view.App keeps crashing

Tags: ios, swift, image, uicollectionview

I keep getting the following message everytime I open the viewcontroller which has the collection view

> [
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key cameraButtonClicked.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x182942db0 0x181fa7f80 0x182942a70 0x18324f6e4 0x187e15de8 0x187f78eb0 0x182866888 0x187f77898
>   0x1881e4b84 0x1881e9c30 0x1881e9e98 0x1881ea184 0x187ad8be8
>   0x187c5d640 0x187ad8be8 0x187ad8b64 0x187ac0870 0x187ac09bc
>   0x187ad8454 0x187ad8084 0x187ad0c20 0x187aa104c 0x19413545c
>   0x187a9f628 0x1828f909c 0x1828f8b30 0x1828f6830 0x182820c50
>   0x184108088 0x187b0a088 0x1000bc9e0 0x1823be8b8) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

The code is given below

```
import UIKit
import Photos
private let reuseIdentifier = "PhotoCell"

class AddPhotoViewController: UIViewController , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate ,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var photoAlbum: UICollectionView!


var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
var photosAsset: PHFetchResult!
var assetThumbnailSize: CGSize!

   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
     super.viewDidLoad()
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

    let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Album, subtype: .Any, options: fetchOptions)

    if let first_Obj:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{
        //found the album
        self.assetCollection = first_Obj as! PHAssetCollection
    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

 @IBAction func cameraButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera)) {

        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil {

            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
            presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: {} )

        } else
        {
            print("cannot access camera")
        }

    } else
    {
        print("cannot access camera")

    }
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    if let layout = self.photoAlbum!.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        let cellSize = layout.itemSize

        self.assetThumbnailSize = CGSizeMake(cellSize.width, cellSize.height)
    }

    //fetch the photos from collection
    self.photosAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self.assetCollection, options: nil)

    self.photoAlbum!.reloadData()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
 func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    var count: Int = 0

    if(self.photosAsset != nil){
        count = self.photosAsset.count
    }

    return count;
}
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell: PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell = photoAlbum.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell


    let asset: PHAsset = self.photosAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: self.assetThumbnailSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
        if let image = result {
            cell.setThumbnailImage(image)
        }
    })

    return cell
 }
 func collectionView(collectinView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

// UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool 
{
    return false
}

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

}

}
```

The code for the collectionview cell is as below

```
import UIKit

class PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
func setThumbnailImage(thumbNailImage: UIImage)
{
    self.imageView.image = thumbNailImage
}
}
```

Please can anyone help me with this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this class is not key value coding-compliant` means that you have an issue with your IBAction linking. In Interface Builder, try to right-click on your button that should call `cameraButtonClicked` method and see if you have a Warning symbol. If so, remove the link and make it again.

Comment: That's probably mean that self.photosAsset is nil, I can't tell you why as I don't know about PHAssetCollection. You should probably ask for this in another question ;)

Comment: First check that your `self.assetCollection` is not nil and then fetch assets from it

Answer (score 0):

Vineeth Krishnan
i agree with Anthonin C.'s answer. Its ur IBOutlet connection issue. GoTo your xib or nib file and remove the connection of your button which connect the "cameraButtonClicked" it will resolve your problem of crash.